# NotSerializableException in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd, serializable

Most of the non-serializable issues online get very basic data as an input for their `sc.parallelize()` and in the map section they encounter the non-serializable issue, but mine is a type. I have a specific data type, which is coming from a third party library and is not serializable. 
So writing this showed NotSerializableException :

```
val data: RDD[ThirdPartyLib.models.XData] = sc.parallelize(ThirdPartyLib.getX)

data.foreachPartition(rows => {
  rows.foreach(row => {
    println("value: " + row.getValue)    
  })  
})
```

As a solution, I created the the same model class(XData) internally but made it serializable and did this:

```
val data: RDD[XData] = (sc.parallelize(ThirdPartyLib.getX)).asInstanceOf[RDD[XData]]

data.foreachPartition(rows => {
  rows.foreach(row => {
    println("value: " + row.getValue)    
  })  
})
```

I was expecting the issue to be resolved, but I am still getting the same error that the `[ERROR] org.apache.spark.util.Utils logError - Exception encountered
 java.io.NotSerializableException: ThirdPartyLib.models.XData`. Shouldn't the problem re resolved when I created that internal serializable type? How can I fix this?

Comment: what is `XData` here? can you share the content of it ?

Comment: I don't know if I can share the content or not. But it is just a simple pojo class with properties and simple getters/setters.

Comment: And does the `ThirdPartyLib.getX` returns list of `XData` objects ?

Comment: Yes. `ThirdPartyLib.getX` returns list of `XData`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So with

```
(sc.parallelize(ThirdPartyLib.getX)).asInstanceOf[RDD[XData]]
```

you parallelize first and then cast. so spark still requires ThirdPartyLib.models.XData to be serializable. Also that cast would probably explode because the types aren't the same.

I think this should do the trick

```
def convertThirdPartyXDataToMyXData( xd: ThirdPartyLib.models.XData): XData = ???

val data: RDD[ThirdPartyLib.models.XData] = sc.parallelize(ThirdPartyLib.getX.map(convertThirdPartyXDataToMyXData)) //if you have a map on the collection that getX returns
```

Comment: I ended up asking the third party library owners to change the classes to Serializable but this answer worked just fine. Thanks